# Javascript URL Location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check to see if part of my url location have this in it:
?TEST=NEWJERSEY

How do i write that?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this if you're looking just for that parameter and there are no others allowed in the URL before it:

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf("?TEST=NEWJERSEY") != -1) {
   // it is present
}
```

If you want to allow for more than just that single parameter so there could be other parameters after the ? and in any order, then you could check it this way:

```
if (window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)TEST=NEWJERSEY($|&)/)) {
    // it is present
}
```